# Why is List wrapped in IntoIter?

Tags: iterator, rust

In the book [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/), in the [implementation](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-into-iter.html) of `IntoIter`, why is `List` wrapped in a tuple struct? Instead, `Iterator` could have been implemented for a `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, technically `Iterator` could be implemented for `List` in this case.  This isn't generally true, since iterators might need different state that's not in the base container (e.g. a `Vec` iterator might need to store an index to the next item to iterate efficiently).

One reason is that if the implementation changes in future and the `List` iterator would be better with extra state, it's possible to change the iterator struct without changing any callers.

Another reason is that in Rust it's common to use types to narrow interfaces to reduce the chance of errors.  If you implement `Iterator` directly (and presumably `IntoIterator` to return `self`), then that leaves the possibility for the user to call other `List` methods during iteration, which is probably wrong.  Instead the iterator is a separate type, meaning that there's no possibility of someone pushing items on during iteration.  (Note that in a `for` loop it'd be hard to do this anyway due to the borrowing/move rules, but the general point is still there).

Comment: Thanks! Even `Iterator` is implemented on `List`, we still can't call `List` methods during iteration because `List` would be moved already, or did I get you wrong?

Comment: That's true in a `for` loop, but it's also possible to use an iterator directly (calling `next`).  This isn't quite the best example of that principle.

Comment: The Iterator trait adds a lot of extension methods, so that's another reason to separate them cleanly. Maybe having a `.map()` method is awesome, but a `last()` that consumes the whole list not so much.